# Can I call continue as a return or invoke it?

Tags: php, callback, return, call

In my loop I have a callback that return true or false.
Depends on the result I have to continue or break my loop.

Now I want this a step easier if possible.
I will return 'continue' or 'break' in my callback and it would be nice to say something like:

```
call($return) // $return => 'continue' or 'break'
```

Is this even possible?

**EDIT**
In a short form:

```
$return = $this->myCallback(...);
if ($return) { break; }
if (!$return) { continue; }
```

Instead I want something like this:

```
$return = $this->myCallback(...);
call($return); // return contains 'continue' or 'break'
```

Comment: Have a look: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Why dont you give it a try?

Comment: It is not possible just say break / continue in the callback.
So my question ist what function or call do I need to call this.

Comment: Why not $continue = true or false?

Comment: @splash58 - I want to try it as shprt as possible. I already receive a boolean but then I have to use another condition to call break or continue.

Comment: maybe, you show fragments of the code?

Comment: Fragments are now in the EDIT block on the top.

Answer (score 0):

no... you can return Boolean from the function and check if you want to break or continue..

Comment: Smells to be comment more.

Comment: uh? is it not that simple?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$return = $this->myCallback(...);
if ($return) { break; }
if (!$return) { continue; }
```

write

```
if($this->myCallback()) break;
else continue;     // if yoг are really need this continue
```

Why not?